# Faster ways of processing in R - CUTOFF

Tags: r, performance

I ask you the following question.
Suppose I have the following database and seek to calculate each of the db distributions (the em function gives the value of each average of a bimodal distribution).
The problem is that processing is very slow.
It takes 2.3 min for only 6 ids (imagine if I have to do it for thousands of ids).
Can you think of another much faster way to process this data (e.g. in parallel, with another function, taking more than one core)?

Thanks!

```
N <- 100000

components <- sample(1:3,prob=c(0.3,0.5,0.2),size=N,replace=TRUE)
mus <- c(0,10,3)
sds <- sqrt(c(1,1,0.1))

samples <- rnorm(n=N,mean=mus[components],sd=sds[components])

db<-data.frame(id=c('a','b','c','d','e','f'),dist=c(samples,samples*0.9,samples*1.1,samples*1.2,samples*0.98,samples*0.88))
db$id<-as.character(db$id)

# install.packages("bbmle")
# devtools::install_github("choisy/cutoff")
library(cutoff)

IDS<-unique(db$id)

system.time(
bimod <- lapply(1:length(unique(db$id)), function(x){
                                        x<-db[db$id==IDS[x],]$dist

                                        tryCatch({ em(x,"normal","normal") }, error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")}) 
  })
)

126.675  11.697 140.838
```

Comment: Try using a matrix rather than a data frame, and rather numbers than characters in your ids. If you depend on characters, probably factors are the better choice. Does this increase your speed? If not take a look into `cutoff::em` and look if you can enhance slow parts.

Comment: Do the profiling. You can see than the `bbmle::mle2` function is taking all the processing time.

Comment: How did you do the profiling? with Rprof? could you reproduce your analysis please?

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + Shift + P in RStudio

Comment: You could try to replace the `bbmle::mle2` part with `stats4::mle` somehow. Might improve since it is much smaller (not tested).